# Invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, syntax

It's a Heap implemented by myself(for algorithm contest).There are some compilation errors that I can't recover from...

```
\Map_Heap.cpp|13|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'MapHeap<DT>::nv'|
\Map_Heap.cpp|19|error: from this location|
```

Code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
const int HEAP_SIZE=10005;
template<class DT>
struct MapHeap
{
    DT f[HEAP_SIZE+5];
    int mp1[HEAP_SIZE+5];//val -> index
    int mp2[HEAP_SIZE+5];//index -> val
    int nv;///line 13
    MapHeap():nv(0)
    {
        memset(mp1,-1,sizeof(mp1));
        memset(mp2,-1,sizeof(mp2));
    }
    void print(int n=nv)//line 19
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%d ",f[i]);
        puts("");
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%d ",mp1[i]);
        puts("");
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%d ",mp2[i]);
        puts("");
    }
};
```

Comment: There are some funny `**`s at the front. Are these part of the code, or were you trying to make that line bold? Because that won't work in code.

Comment: I were just trying to make that line bold and I found it didn't work...>_<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply saying that you can't base a default argument on a member variable.  Consider using overloads instead:

```
void print() { print(nv); }
void print(int n) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it mentioned explicitly in the Standards that "you can't base a default argument on a member variable?

Comment: wow..It's cool.. It's just steer clear of the problem...(I am not a English native speaker...sorry for my poor English if I make any misunderstanding)

Comment: @Mr.TAMER. Actually, yes.  See 8.3.6, clause 9: "a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument expression".